# Replacing words tagged by #word# within a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to search and replace words between the two `#` marks.

The text is random (users add it).

Example:

```
text = "hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!"
```

I need to cut the two words between `#` (word1 and word2) and change the words to title case - `.title()`.

Desired output:

```
"hello this #Word1# a it #Word2# thanks!"
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the `#` marks in the final text, or remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a regular expression:

```
import re

text = 'hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!'
print re.sub('#(\w+)#', lambda m:m.group(1).title(), text)
```

Output:

> hello this Word1 a it Word2 thanks!

**Edit**

If you want to retain the bounding # characters, use noncapturing expressions:

```
print re.sub('(?<=#)(\w+)(?=#)', lambda m:m.group(1).title(), text)
```

Output:

> hello this #Word1# a it #Word2# thanks!

Comment: How to do that Output: hello this #Word1# a it #Word2# thanks!

Comment: Hi @user3697586, see my edit above!

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!".split()
result = ' '.join([w[1:-1].title() if w[0] == '#' else w for w in s])
```

gives

```
'hello this Word1 a it Word2 thanks!'
```

and

```
s = "hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!".split()
result = ' '.join([w.title() if w[0] == '#' else w for w in s])
```

gives

```
'hello this #Word1# a it #Word2# thanks!'
```